# R: filter result from selectInput by renderUI shiny with if condition

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, render

In the example below, I have four selectInput, but in my real shiny app I actually have six. I would like the selection in the first tree selectInput(major,gender,course) to change the possible selections in the last one(studentname). So the first three selectInput works like filters of the last one.

- For example, if the user chooses "male" in gender selectInput, then
  the options in studentname selectInput should only displays the name
  of male student.
- If user chooses "male" in gender selectInput and "A"    in major
  selectInput, then the options in studentname selectInput    should
  only display the name of male student in major A.

I have some code below, but it doesn't work well. Thanks a lot if anyone could help!

Here is data example

```
df = data.frame(Studentname = c("aa","aa","aa","bb","bb","bb","cc","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg"),
                Major = c("A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","A","A","C","C"),
                Gender = c("female","female","female","male","male","male","male","male","female","female","male","male"), Course = c("01","02","03","01","03","04","02","04","01","03","02","04"),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

code:

```
 library(shiny)

ui = (fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("choose_maj"),
      uiOutput("choose_gen"),
      uiOutput("choose_cou"),
      uiOutput("choose_stu")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
  
))

server = function(input,output,session){
  output$choose_maj = renderUI({
    selectInput("maj.in","Choose Major",
                choices = c("All",unique(df$Major)),selected="All")
  })
  
  output$choose_gen = renderUI({
    selectInput("gen.in","Choose Gender", 
                choices= c("Both",unique(df$Gender)),selected = "Both")
  })
  
  output$choose_cou = renderUI({
    selectInput("cou.in","Choose Course", 
                choices= c("All",unique(df$Course)),selected = "All")
  })
  
  output$choose_stu = renderUI({
    
    if(input$maj.in != "All"){
      dat <- df[which(df$Major == input$maj.in),]
  
    }
    if(input$gen.in != "Both"){
      dat <- df[which(df$Gender == input$gen.in),]

    }
    if(input$cou.in != "All"){
      dat <- df[which(df$Course == input$cou.in),]
    }
    
    selectInput("stu.in", "Choose Student Name", 
                choices  = as.list(unique(dat$Studentname)),
                selected = "All")
  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just provide a copy of your `data.frame` to your `renderUI` function you can do all the different subsets.

This works for me:

```
output$choose_stu = renderUI({

    dat <- df

    if(input$maj.in != "All"){
        dat <- dat[which(dat$Major == input$maj.in),]

    }
    if(input$gen.in != "Both"){
        dat <- dat[which(dat$Gender == input$gen.in),]

    }
    if(input$cou.in != "All"){
        dat <- dat[which(dat$Course == input$cou.in),]
    }

    selectInput("stu.in", "Choose Student Name", 
                choices  = as.list(unique(dat$Studentname)),
                selected = "All")
})
```

Comment: Thanks. But seems like the logic of if condition is not correct? For example, if I choose major A and male, it returns a wrong name list. Also, if I choose female and course 01, the result is also wrong.

Comment: @ouou, the output is correct for me.  Major A & male returns none and female/course 01 returns aa and dd. You sure you overwrote the previous `renderUI` and ran everything again?

Comment: Sorry I didn't overwrote all of them. It works very well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you explain why the copy of df in renderUI is needed? I don't quite understand.

Comment: @ouou Because with your initial logic, only the last filter will be applied directly on the `df` object.  If you want multiple filters you need to apply the filters on the previously filtered object.  Try some subsets by hand to see it in action.

Comment: Actually, it runs, but it returns an error message "Error in if (input$maj.in != "All") { : argument is of length zero". Do you know how do I fix the code?

Comment: @ouou That is a consequence of the shiny app startup.  You could just add a `validate` statement and it would go away.          `validate(need(!is.null(input$maj.in), "require a major input"))`

Comment: I post another question here. Can you have a look to see if you could help? Thanks a lot! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267604/switch-ggivs-plots-based-on-radio-buttons-in-r-shiny